# Using ORDER BY when merging prioritised records from different users

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble with a complex 'ORDER BY' which is also a bit of a tricky one to explain (it may also not be possible!).

Let's say I have 2 customers who each raise 3 support tickets (into a SQL database) and later set a Priority for each one. The two result sets would look something like this (ordered by Priority):

```
USER   | SUBJECT | PRIORITY   | DATESTAMP
-------+---------+------------+----------------
THOMAS | Error A | Priority 1 | 20/11/2017 08:01
THOMAS | Error C | Priority 2 | 20/11/2017 10:30
THOMAS | Error B | Priority 3 | 20/11/2017 14:55

USER   | SUBJECT | PRIORITY   | DATESTAMP
-------+---------+------------+----------------
HENRY  | Error B | Priority 1 | 20/11/2017 11:14
HENRY  | Error A | Priority 2 | 20/11/2017 18:44
HENRY  | Error C | Priority 3 | 20/11/2017 16:26
```

This is where it gets complicated (I think): let's say I then wanted to combine these lists to create a 'master list' of support tickets, ordered appropriately to create a task list for a technician. This `ORDER BY` would need to use the Datestamp to ensure earlier tickets were resolved first, but also honour the Priority numbers assigned by the users to address more important jobs before others. The resulting table should look something like this:

```
USER   | SUBJECT | PRIORITY   | DATESTAMP
-------+---------+------------+----------------
THOMAS | Error A | Priority 1 | 20/11/2017 08:01
THOMAS | Error C | Priority 2 | 20/11/2017 10:30
HENRY  | Error B | Priority 1 | 20/11/2017 11:14
THOMAS | Error B | Priority 3 | 20/11/2017 14:55
HENRY  | Error A | Priority 2 | 20/11/2017 18:44
HENRY  | Error C | Priority 3 | 20/11/2017 16:26
```

Currently, I am struggling to achieve this.

If I order them by the Datetime field first this essentially ignores the Priority because all of the dates are different.

If I order them by the Priority field first, I get this:

```
USER   | SUBJECT | PRIORITY   | DATESTAMP
-------+---------+------------+----------------
THOMAS | Error A | Priority 1 | 20/11/2017 08:01
HENRY  | Error B | Priority 1 | 20/11/2017 11:14
THOMAS | Error C | Priority 2 | 20/11/2017 10:30
HENRY  | Error A | Priority 2 | 20/11/2017 18:44
THOMAS | Error B | Priority 3 | 20/11/2017 14:55
HENRY  | Error C | Priority 3 | 20/11/2017 16:26
```

The problem here is that Henry's tickets are being bumped too high up the list--his Priority 1 should be after Thomas' Priorities 1 AND 2, because it was logged at a later time.

I feel like this can't be fixed by simply rearranging the order of the fields in the `ORDER BY`, if it can be done at all, but I can't think of a way around it. Is there some special multi-layered approach which can achieve this, or am I just being stupid? Thanks!

Comment: I cannot figure out what the logic is for the ordering.

Comment: Yeah this is impossible with the way you have worded it. If you want the highest priority first, how can you also expect that Henry's priority 1 be after Thomas', unless you order by Date, which you explicitly stated you don't want... your expected results show simply order by date--ignoring the priority altogether.

Comment: not quite the sorting logic.

Comment: As i understand, it is ordered by Date. For one individual though, his priority order override the global Date order so Henry can't have his priority 2 after his priority 3 even if the Date order says so

Comment: May I have worded it wrong. Or maybe it's just not doable. But yes, it's kind of like saying "Show me all of the tickets in date order, but for each individual person be sure to override that date order with their priority setting." My brain hurts...

Comment: @valoukh If you use a table ordered by priority where if the next row date value is older you change it to the upper row date value, you do this for each individual then you order by DATE, PRIORITY. So in the case of Henry Priority 2 would have 18:44 and Priority 3 same thing, 18:44. At least for your example it will work. You don't need to change the row value, just return the new value. Sorry my wording is terrible, but the question messed up my head!

Answer (score 0):

Okay i'm not perfectly sure with this one and i never used [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) before. It should return previous row value. I gave my explanation in the comments on the question. Quickly put : Order by datestamp, but if the priority for certain individual is not in chronological order, than change it to reflect priority first by putting older ticket with greater priority same datestamp as newer ticket this lesser priority.

Edit : `LAG` now use newdate

```
SELECT UserName, Subject, Priority, DateStamp
FROM T
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT UserName, DateStamp,
    CASE WHEN LAG(newdate, 1, DateStamp) OVER (Partition BY UserName ORDER BY Priority) > DateStamp 
         THEN LAG(newdate, 1, DateStamp) OVER (Partition By UserName ORDER BY Priority)
         ELSE DateStamp END AS newdate
    FROM T as x ) AS x ON x.UserName = t.UserName
ORDER BY x.newdate, T.Priority
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot - thanks so much for looking into it

Comment: I'm struggling to get this working. The LAG function is interesting and I'd not heard of this before, but it seems that only referring to the previous row isn't quite putting them in the right order...

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008 so i can't even test my own query, but i think i found the problem. By adding partition by, the new subtables are order by the priority of only one user, before it was for all users. Furthermore, by using 'newdate' in the LAG it should make the order right. I'm not sure on this second part with newdate though.

Answer (score 0):

Order them by the "Due Date".  I assume each of your priorties has some form of SLA associated with it.  Add the SLA to the DATESTAMP to determine when it should be due.  Ordering by this value ensures that your lower priority tickets will eventually come up in the queue, but still requires the higher priority tickets to be resolved quicker.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
  UserName  VARCHAR(10),
  Subject   VARCHAR(10),
  Priority  INT,
  DateStamp DATETIME
)
;

INSERT INTO @T (UserName,
                Subject,
                Priority,
                DateStamp
               )
VALUES ('THOMAS', 'Error A', 1, '20171120 08:01'),
('THOMAS', 'Error C', 2, '20171120 10:30'),
('THOMAS', 'Error B', 3, '20171120 14:55'),
('HENRY', 'Error B', 1, '20171120 11:14'),
('HENRY', 'Error A', 2, '20171120 18:44'),
('HENRY', 'Error C', 3, '20171120 16:26')
;

SELECT      UserName,
            Subject,
            Priority,
            DateStamp,
            DueDate = CASE Priority
                        WHEN 1
                          THEN DATEADD( HOUR, 2, DateStamp )
                        WHEN 2
                          THEN DATEADD( HOUR, 12, DateStamp )
                        WHEN 3
                          THEN DATEADD( HOUR, 24, DateStamp )
                        ELSE DATEADD( HOUR, 72, DateStamp )
                      END
  FROM      @T
  ORDER BY  DueDate
```

This also makes it very easy to see the impact of your SLA threshholds.

```
UserName   Subject    Priority    DateStamp               DueDate
---------- ---------- ----------- ----------------------- -----------------------
THOMAS     Error A    1           2017-11-20 08:01:00.000 2017-11-20 10:01:00.000
HENRY      Error B    1           2017-11-20 11:14:00.000 2017-11-20 13:14:00.000
THOMAS     Error C    2           2017-11-20 10:30:00.000 2017-11-20 22:30:00.000
HENRY      Error A    2           2017-11-20 18:44:00.000 2017-11-21 06:44:00.000
THOMAS     Error B    3           2017-11-20 14:55:00.000 2017-11-21 14:55:00.000
HENRY      Error C    3           2017-11-20 16:26:00.000 2017-11-21 16:26:00.000
```

---

*UPDATED*

---

I've added some additional records and included some priority 4 values to better show how they will distribute.

```
UserName   Subject    Priority    DateStamp               DueDate
---------- ---------- ----------- ----------------------- -----------------------
HENRY      Error A    2           2017-11-19 19:44:00.000 2017-11-20 07:44:00.000
THOMAS     Error A    1           2017-11-20 08:01:00.000 2017-11-20 10:01:00.000
HENRY      Error B    1           2017-11-20 11:14:00.000 2017-11-20 13:14:00.000
THOMAS     Error C    2           2017-11-20 10:30:00.000 2017-11-20 22:30:00.000
HENRY      Error D    2           2017-11-20 12:44:00.000 2017-11-21 00:44:00.000
THOMAS     Error B    3           2017-11-20 14:55:00.000 2017-11-21 14:55:00.000
HENRY      Error C    3           2017-11-20 16:26:00.000 2017-11-21 16:26:00.000
HENRY      Error F    4           2017-11-18 18:44:00.000 2017-11-21 18:44:00.000
HENRY      Error C    2           2017-11-21 08:44:00.000 2017-11-21 20:44:00.000
HENRY      Error B    2           2017-11-21 18:44:00.000 2017-11-22 06:44:00.000
HENRY      Error E    4           2017-11-19 18:44:00.000 2017-11-22 18:44:00.000
```

Comment: This is a very elegant solution and has given me some great ideas to try out, thank you! It unfortunately doesn't get around the issue that the 3rd row (Thomas Error C) should be 2nd because 10:30 is earlier than 11:14... :/

Comment: The 3rd row is priority 2, the 2nd row is priority 1, The timestamps are only 45 minutes apart.  What did you mean when you wanted to "Honor Priority"?  What is your desired resolution timeframe for Priority 1 & Priority 2?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that, as stated, your criteria for sorting results in a comparison operator that is *non-transitive*. Consider:

```
Thomas | Priority 1 | 10:00
Thomas | Priority 2 | 08:00
Henry  | Priority 1 | 09:00
```

Now, you want Thomas Priority 1 > Thomas Priority 2, but also Thomas Priority 2 > Henry Priority 1 because of the timestamps, AND Henry Priority 1 > Thomas Priority 1 because of timestamps, so you have A > B > C > A.

This means that there is no total ordering of the set of tickets, and, therefore, you cannot meaningfully sort them. Math here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order.

Comment: Here the tickets would be Henry(1) - Thomas(1) - Thomas(2). He wants Henry(1)  before Thomas(1) because of the timestamp, and Thomas(1) before Thomas(2) because of the priority. For a single individual, his priority override his timestamp, so Thomas(2) must be considered after Thomas(1), no matter Henry's priorities. So for the order, Thomas(2) is after Thomas(1) if your consider that his timestamp is the same and order by timestamp AND priority. That would do Henry(1) - Thomas(1) - Thomas(2) *considered at 10:00*

Comment: But Thomas(2) was *before* Henry(1) . Consider what would happen if Thomas(1) was not present.

Comment: But Thomas(2) timestamp was before Henry(1) timestamp and Thomas(1) also, in your exemple, Thomas(1) is after Henry(1), so Thomas(2) turns to 'after 10:00'

Comment: While this may be viable business logic, it relies on an assumption not present in the question - *where is it stated that the dates are changed?* The question says "I then wanted to combine these lists to create a 'master list' of support tickets, ordered appropriately", implying an ordering, nowhere do I see timestamps being changed.

Comment: As i stated on my other comments on the main question and in my own answer, the timestamp are not changed, it's just simpler to think of them as changed, that's why i used the word "considered". The "new" timestamp is temporary just for the sake of ordering, in my logic, it could be flawed, but for now it seems to work on paper. By doing this, you can now order by "new timestamp" and priority, sorry for the confusion

Comment: I think you might be right @MartinMarkov... I am starting to think it's a paradox. I certainly feels like one.